# A unit ball is not a regular surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces

Recall that a set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$ is called a *regular surface* if for every $p\in S$, there exists an open neighborhood $B_p$ of $p$, and also an open set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ and a function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f(A) = B_p\cap S$, $f$ is injective and continuously differentiable, and $Df$ is of rank 2.

I am asked to prove the very intuitive result that the solid unit ball is not a regular surface.
Although ridiculously trivial result, the proof seems to be very hard and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Are you familiar with Sard's Theorem?

Comment: @AlexS I am not familiar with it, how does it imply the result?

Comment: Sard's Theorem states that if $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ is continuously differentiable, then the set of points $$\{f(x):Df(x)\text{ has rank less than $m$}\}$$ has Lebesgue measure zero. Since for your function, $Df(x)$ always has rank less than $m$, its image must have Lebesgue measure $0$, so its image cannot contain any nonempty open set in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: That seems too fancy. How 'bout using the fact that the tangent space of $\Bbb R^3$ at any point is $3$-dimensional, not $2$-dimensional?